# FriendPicker in Facebook C# SDK

Tags: c#, facebook, sdk

I'm trying to get the Demo of the FriendPicker for Windows Phone to work.

[FriendPicker Control](http://facebooksdk.net/docs/phone/controls/friendpicker-ui-control/)

It logs in OK but no friends are displayed.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Show your code as well..

Comment: The code is the same as the code in the link